# how to mock jdbcTemplate.query() with rs as an argument in query method?

Tags: springmockito

Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{number}, rs -> {
            if (rs.next()) {
            Info prf = new Info();
            prf.setName(rs.getString(1));
            prf.setId(rs.getInt(2));
            prf.setNo(rs.getString(3));
            return perf;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I did the below and it worked.
@Mock
JDBCTemplate jdbcTemplate

Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), (Object[]) anyObject(), any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenReturn(perf);